# Movesense Peak detectiion trigger

Tags: movesense

On the Maxim EKG chip, INT2B can be set as a peak detection trigger.  How do I send a BT notification, preferably with a timestamp as soon as possible through the Nordic platform?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Movesense architecture there is no direct access to hardware, everything happens via Movesense API (defined in *MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api* as ".yaml"-files).

The Maxim 30003 peak detection is accessed via */Meas/HR* -resource which gives notification each time a peak is detected. That resource can be subscribed to directly from the mobile (via the MDS library, see: movesense-mobile-lib). The delay from the actual peak to the mobile notification should be relatively constant and dominated by Maxim chips detection delay (read: I have not measured). The BLE connection causes itself some delay that should be 20-100ms or so depending on the BLE connection parameters etc. This is the way I'd go for since later when we add the timestamp to /Meas/HR (it has been requested from us already) it's a simple modification to use the included timestamp.

Alternatively you can write your own sensor app (firmware) with its own API, that can subscribe to /Meas/HR and for each notification do GET to */Time/Detailed* and return just the timestamp each time a peak is detected. For a starting point for that I'd recommend the jumpmeter_app and modify it accordingly.

*Full disclaimer: I work for Movesense team*